# Spring boot problema con API y mi metodo GET a su vez problema con el POST

Tags: java, mysql, spring

resulta que tengo un problema con mi entidad Factura cuando quiero hacer un get de la factura o un getAll me tira error de serializable. La ultima vez lo pude solucionar agregandole @JsonIgnore a todas las relaciones JPA, pero cuando hago esto mi metodo POST deja de funcionar. Hago el post de una factura en el que tiene un cliente relacionado y el campo id_cliente de mi factura siempre queda null. (Cuando no tengo el JsonIgnore anda perfectamente). Les dejo mis entidades: Factura - Cliente - Producto y mi controlador y servicio de Factura.

```
package com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo;



import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter

public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_cliente;

    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private String apellido;
    @Column
    @JsonProperty("dni")
    private String dni;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Factura> comprobantesVentas = new ArrayList<>();
}
package com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Factura {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_factura")
    private Integer id_factura;

    @Column
    private LocalDate fecha;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "Factura_producto",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_factura"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_producto"))
    private List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.fecha = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public void addProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.productos.add(producto);
    }
}
package com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Producto {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Integer id_producto;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private double precio;
    @Column
    private int stock;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productos", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Factura> comprobantesVenta = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

Ahora dejo mi controlador y servicio Factura:

```
package com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Controladores;


import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo.Factura;
import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo.Producto;
import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Servicios.ServicioFactura;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/facturas")
public class ControladorFactura {


    @Autowired
    ServicioFactura servicioFactura;

    // GET ALL
    @GetMapping()
    public List<Factura> getFacturas(){
        return servicioFactura.getAll();
    }

    // GET POR ID
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Factura getFactura(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return servicioFactura.getFacturaById(id);
    }

    // POST -
    @PostMapping("/alta")
    public String postFactura(@RequestBody Factura Factura) {
        return servicioFactura.guardarFactura(Factura);
    }

    // PUT - ADD Producto a la Factura
    @PutMapping("/add/{id}")
    public String addProducto(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Producto producto) {
        return servicioFactura.addProductoToFactura(id, producto);
    }

    // GET PRECIO FACTURA
        @GetMapping("/precio/{id}")
        public double getTotalPriceById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
            return servicioFactura.getTotalPriceById(id);
        }

    // DELETE
    @DeleteMapping("/baja/{id}")
    public String deleteFactura(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return servicioFactura.deleteFacturaByID(id);
    }

    // GET TODOS LOS PRODUCTOS DE UNA FACTURA
    @GetMapping("/productos/{id}")
    public List<Producto> getProductosById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return servicioFactura.getProductosById(id);
    }

    //DELETE ALL
    @DeleteMapping("/borrarTodos")
    public String deleteAllFacturas() {
        return servicioFactura.deleteAllFacturas();
    }
}
package com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Servicios;

import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo.Factura;
import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Modelo.Producto;
import com.example.TrabajoFinalCoder.Repositorios.RepositorioFactura;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ServicioFactura {
    @Autowired
    RepositorioFactura repositorioFactura;


    // GET ALL
    public List<Factura> getAll() {
        return repositorioFactura.findAll();
    }

    // GET ID
    public Factura getFacturaById(Integer facturaID) {
        return repositorioFactura.getReferenceById(facturaID);
    }

    // POST
    public String guardarFactura(Factura factura) {
        repositorioFactura.save(factura);
        return "guardado";

    }

    // PUT - ADD Producto a la Factura.
    public String addProductoToFactura(Integer comprobanteId, Producto producto) {
        Optional<Factura> optionalFactura = repositorioFactura.findById(comprobanteId);
        if (optionalFactura.isPresent()) {
            Factura factura = optionalFactura.get();
            factura.addProducto(producto);
            repositorioFactura.save(factura);
            return "Producto agregado a la Factura";
        } else {
            return "Factura inválida";
        }
    }

    // GET PRECIO DE Factura
    public double getTotalPriceById(Integer facturaID) {
        Optional<Factura> optionalFactura = repositorioFactura.findById(facturaID);
        double resultado = 0;
        for (Producto hijo : optionalFactura.get().getProductos()) {
            resultado += hijo.getPrecio();
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    // DELETE
    public String deleteFacturaByID(Integer facturaID) {
        Optional<Factura> optionalFactura = repositorioFactura.findById(facturaID);
        if (optionalFactura.isPresent()) {
            repositorioFactura.deleteById(facturaID);
            return "Eliminado";
        } else {
            return "Comprobante no encontrado";
        }
    }

    // GET TODOS LOS PRODUCTOS DE UNA FACTURA

    public List<Producto> getProductosById(Integer facturaID) {
        Optional<Factura> optionalFactura = repositorioFactura.findById(facturaID);
        return optionalFactura.map(Factura::getProductos).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
    }


    // DELETE ALL
    public String deleteAllFacturas() {
        repositorioFactura.deleteAll();
        return "Eliminados";
    }
}
```

Gracias espero su ayuda!
PD: Sigo sin solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

A ver vamos por partes.

1. no devuelvas un string queda muy feo. devuelve un
   ResponseEntity,eso devuelve si todo va bien un codigo 200 y la factura guardada
2. nunca se expone la entidad, debes crear un dto que es la misma clase
   pero sin las anotaciones de jpa y devuleves esa, y tp se pasa como
   parametro la entidad siempre el dto y se transforma una clase en
   otra.
3. pon jsonignore en aquellas que crean recursividad infinita, dentro de factura en cliente,y dentro de producto en factura.
4. @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
   private List comprobantesVentas;
   eso del new arraylist fuera, eso ya se inicializa con el constructor sin parametros solo.
5. La realacion factura productos esta mal. un producto solo puede estar en una factura(no se lo  puedes vender a varios clietnes) pero una factua tiene varios productos por tanto es many to one y no many to many
6. lo de post.Pongamos varios caso.
   si quieres craer un cliente creas quel cliente y haces el save.
   Si quieres crear facturas, cada factura va asoaciada a un cliente(que ya existe) entonces creas la factura y luego debes setearle el cliente del que es la facutra y luego hacer el save.

Luego si quieres crear productos creas lo que quieras y una vez vayan a una factura sacas los productos que quieres de la BD le seteas la factura que le correspone y haces de nuevo el save.

para que te hagas uan idea de como se hace un poco mas nivel pro(un poco que tp se mucho :P)
https://github.com/carlos033/PruebaInditex